# Execution Timeout Expired in nested query with Group By in .NET Core 6

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-core, query-optimization

I have this query to fetch the data from Database, but the problem is taking too much time until the it throws below exception:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I tried to add below line in Program.cs

```cs
opt.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalSeconds);
```

but that will not solve the issue and even thought it throws the same exception again.

the query is:

```cs
result =  await _context.SomeObjects
    .AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Location, x.Date })
    .Select(x => new MyObject
    {
        Date = x.Key.Date,
        Location = x.Key.Location,
        MaxValue = x.Max(x => x.Value),
        MinValue = x.Min(x => x.Value),
        Mean = x.Select(x => (double)x.Value).Mean() ,
        Value = x.Sum(x=>(long)x.Value),
        Median = x.Select(x=> (double)x.Value).Median(),
        Open = x.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).First().Value
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Is there anyway to enhance the query, I tried many approach but in every try it throws different exception.

Update:
After start using

```
MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
```

it start throwing

> Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either   parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to
> uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side.   This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type.
> This can   also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of   grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key
> properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain   simple property access expressions.

but this is not the main issue the main issue is with below line

```
 Open = x.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).First().Value
```

If I commented it out the query will working fine.

Comment: First fix the median calculation. It's not correct. Then look at the usual suspects: indexes, statistics.

Comment: Try without `Open` property, then explain what is it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's working fine without open, open value its the first value in the day

Comment: @GertArnold I installed MathNet.Numerics.Statistics and it should be fixed (I mean the median )

Comment: Which EF Core version and can you post which SQL was generated?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.10 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.10

Comment: Then show how you apply `MathNet.Numerics.Statistics`. We need to see the actually working and correct query. You'll probably get a query that can't be translated into SQL and EF will first get all data from the database and do the Select client-side.

Comment: Try the following `Open = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Value).First()`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did, and same exception

Comment: So, that confirms my suspicion. EF needs all data client-side to be able to execute the Mean and Median functions. I think the error means that EF would be able to translate the entire query into SQL if it wasn't for the parts that need all data client-side. In other words, there's a conflict in translation strategies that EF can't solve.

Comment: @GertArnold, I think you are wrong, most likely generated query is very ineffective.

Comment: @Svyatoslav What I understand (but it's getting a bit hazy now) is that query as shown doesn't even run because it throws.

Comment: @GertArnold but how could I get the the value for the first date in grouping result without doing this line Open = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Value).First()?

Comment: So, now I have to issues, one of them is I need to fetch all data on the client side to calculate the Mean and Median and Open value need too much time to be calculated!

Comment: Actually better to write Stored Procedure and write correct query with Window Functions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I think you are correct, I don't think ORM can handle my calculations especially with huge amount of data, I will do more search then If I didn't find any solution I will go with Stored procedure option.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only get the raw data client-side (i.e. Date, Location, Value) by a simple, flat query. That may be a lot of data, but still run quickly enough. Then you can do the rest in-memory.

Comment: @GertArnold once I get the all data on client side by 
 _context.SomeObjects.AsNoTracking().AsParallel().ToList() then do the grouping and my query no exception appear

Comment: @GertArnold but that will affect on the performance

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question, I got  the hint of solution from **@GertArnold**,
and I think there is an optimal solution which mentioned by **@SvyatoslavDanyliv** by comments, he suggested to do that by Stored Procedure and I think this is the optimal solution for huge amount of data, but the solution that let the code work without any exception is fetching data to backend side then do my calculations (doing the calculations by .NET).

### Here is the code:

Note: I'm using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics NuGet package to calculate the Median

```
  var allData =  _context.SomeObjects.AsNoTracking().AsParallel().ToList();

 var result= allData.GroupBy(x => new { x.Location, x.Date }).Select(x =>
                     {


var Values = x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Value).AsEnumerable();
                        

                         return new MyObject
                         {
                             Date = x.Key.Date,
                             Location = x.Key.Location,
                             MaxValue = x.Max(x => x.Value),
                             MinValue = x.Min(x => x.Value),
                             Mean = x.Select(x => (double)x.Value).Mean(),
                             Value = x.Sum(x => (long)x.Value),
                             Median = x.Select(x => (double)x.Value).Median(),
                             Open = Values.First(),
                             Close = Values.Last(),
                         };
                     }
                     ).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: In my comment I also suggested to narrow down the number of properties (columns) you get from the database: `_context.SomeObjects.Select(x => new { x. ... }`. Only fetch what you need. That may reduce the amount of data (and hence, time required) significantly. Also, using `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` prevents storing an intermediate result.